# select only last try

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Consider the following table structure for an imaginary table named `score`:

```
player_name   |player_lastname   |try   |score   
 primary key: (player_name,player_lastname,try)
```

(dont discuss the table schema, its just an example)

This table holds the scores of all players - every player should be able to play either one OR two times. Now, how could I fetch data about every player's last try only (i.e. first tries should be ignored for those who played more than once)?

An example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
player_name,player_lastname,try,score
=====================================
bart, simpson,1,250
lisa,simpson,1,150
lisa,simpson,2,250
homer,simpson,1,300
homer,simpson,2,350
maggi,simpson,1,50
```

The result should be:

```
player_name,player_lastname,try,score
=====================================
bart, simpson,1,250
lisa,simpson,2,250
homer,simpson,2,350
maggi,simpson,1,50
```

Comment: Where is the count of times stored?

Comment: the fild "try" conatains the number of the try: "1" or "2", its not a count but a number, RDBMS: postgresql

Comment: I added tags `postgresql` and `greatest-n-per-group`.  My apologies I had to remove two other tags, there is a limit of five tags per question on Stack Overflow.  Follow the link for the tag `greatest-n-per-group`, because variations on this question have been discussed many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Rank function can solve this:

```
SELECT player_name,player_lastname,TRY,score
FROM  (SELECT player_name,player_lastname,TRY,score,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY player_name, Player_Lastname ORDER BY TRY DESC)AS try_rank
       FROM score
       )sub
WHERE try_rank = 1
```

I'm assuming 'try' is the number that can be 1/2.

Edit, forgot Partition BY

Answer (score 3):

One option is to `JOIN` the table to itself using a subquery with `MAX`:

```
select s.*
from score s
  join (
    select max(try) maxtry, player_name, player_lastname
    from score
    group by player_name, player_lastname
    ) s2 on s.player_name = s2.player_name
      and s.player_lastname = s2.player_lastname
      and s.try = s2.maxtry
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8fe3/2)

Depending on your database, you may be able to take advantage of analytic functions such as `ROW_NUMBER()` though which would make this easier.  Here is a [another fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b8fe3/1) to demonstrate.

---

Since you are using postgresql, then you should be able to use the analytic `ROW_NUMBER()` function.  This should work as well:

```
select *
from (
    select try, player_name, player_lastname, score, 
      Row_Number() Over (Partition By player_name, player_lastname order by try desc) rn
    from score
    ) s
where rn = 1
```

BTW -- I'd consider adding a player_id as a primary key.

Answer (score 3):

This will probably have the best performance

```
select distinct on (player_name, player_lastname)
    player_name, player_lastname, try, score
from score
order by 1, 2, 3 desc
```

Comment: Clearest and most elegant. Once again `distinct on` shows its strength.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
Sel player_name,
player_lastname,
try,
score 
from score where try = 2 or
try = 1 and
(player_name,player_lastname) not in
(sel player_name,player_lastname from score where try=2);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not an sql query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT player_name,player_lastname,try,score
FROM scores sc
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM scores nx
  WHERE nx.player_name = sc.player_name
  AND nx.player_lastname = sc.player_lastname
  AND nx.try > sc.try
  );
```